# MS Access - SQL Query question

Tags: sql, ms-access

System: Windows7, Access 2003, .mdb file, C# language, VS 2010

I'm doing queries with OleDbCommand, so I write the complete sql query in a string.

---

```
Table Survey  (Id)  
Table Questions  (Id,IdSurvey)  
Table Answers (Id,IdQuestion)
```

*the tables are simplified to show only relevant data*

Assume 1 survey has 1..n questions
Assume 1 question has 0..n answers

I want to select only the surveys that have the answers 1 and/or 2 for the Question3, how do I do that?

Current (and poor) solution:

```
SELECT surv.Name FROM Survey surv WHERE 
(1 IN (SELECT answ.Number FROM Answers answ, Questions quest 
WHERE quest.Id = 3 AND quest.IdSurvey = surv.Id) 
AND/OR 
(2 IN (SELECT answ.Number FROM Answers answ, Questions quest
WHERE quest.Id = 3 AND quest.IdSurvey = surv.Id)))
```

This looks like crap, so I would appreciate help.

Thanks in advance.

---

**EDIT**

Better solution i came up with:

For **1 OR 2**, the solutions given    here are enough (for very simple logical expressions). Thanks guys

For **1 AND 2**, i have created    another solution, looks kinda good i    think (again, for very simple logical expressions)

```
SELECT surv.Name FROM Survey surv WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Answers answ, Questions quest 
WHERE quest.Id = 3 AND answ.Number IN (1,2) HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

The "**1**" in the **HAVING** clause means that at least two lines are needed, and since the answers dont repeat for the same questions, this necesseraly means that at least the answers **1 AND 2** exists for the queried question.

Well, both the **OR** solution and the **AND** solution are bad when dealing with more complex logical expressions, like **(1 AND (2 OR (4 AND (6 OR 7) ) ) )**, truth is, its highly unlikely that such complexity will be needed, but i'd like to be safe. The ideal solution for me would be this:

```
SELECT surv.Name FROM Survey surv WHERE 
(1 IN (SELECT answ.Number FROM Answers answ, Questions quest 
WHERE quest.Id = 3 AND quest.IdSurvey = surv.Id) AS CANT_DO_THIS
AND/OR 
(2 IN CANT_DO_THIS) AND/OR 5 IN CANT_DO_THIS AND/OR 3 NOT IN CANT_DO_THIS)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT surv.Name FROM Survery surv
    INNER JOIN Questions quest ON surv.ID = quest.IDSurvey
    INNER JOIN Answers answ ON quest.ID = answ.IDQuestion
    WHERE quest.ID = 3 AND answ.Number IN (1, 2)
```

This will return one line per survey (because you're linking in only question ID 3 and the single answer to that question), and only for surveys where the answer to question 3 is 1 or 2.

NOTE: It's not clear to me how you join the Questions and Answer table in your data model, so I assumed that the Answers table has a foreign key back to Questions called IDQuestion.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
As i described, one question has many answers, so i believe your solution may return the same survey many times. Please note that this introduces the "and" problem, how can i do that with a single "IN" ? Doesnt seem possible.

Comment: If each question is joined, via a foreign key, back to a single survey and each answer is joined, via a foreign key, back to a single question then the SQL should give you the correct result.  I'm not sure whether your model associates each answer with a single _question_, that's a necessary condition to having the three-table join work.

Comment: The problem is that many answers are joined to a single question. And thus, the same survey and same question are repeated over N lines.
It is a '1 x 0..n' relationship. Also, how to do the "1 and 2", instead of the "1 or 2"? (your solution is for "1 or 2", the IN operator)

Answer (score 0):

```
Select ...
From Survey As 
Where Exists    (
                Select 1
                From Questions As Q1
                    Join Answers As A1
                        On A1.IdQuestion = Q1.Id
                Where Q1.IdSurvey = S.Id
                    And Q1.Id = 3
                    And A1.Id In(1,2)
                Having Count(*) = 2
                )
```

Comment: What if i want the answers to be "1 AND 2" instead of being "1 OR 2". Note that your solution is for "1 OR 2", the IN operator.

Comment: @WoF_Angel - Ok. Simple fix. Just add a Having Clause. Have updated my post.

Comment: @WoF_Angel - Btw, my confusion as to what you wanted stemmed from this statement: `select only the surveys that have the answers 1 and/or 2 for the Question3`. Clearly you meant "answers 1 and 2". I took it to mean "1 or 2". On another note, what does the `/` represent in `and/or`? ;>

Comment: it is just a way to abbreviate, i merely want to know the solution for both the "1 and 2" , "1 or 2" cases. It has nothing to do with SQL or any other language. Thanks for your idea, however, do you know a solution that would work for more complex logical expressions (made by many ORs and ANDs)? My crappy solution seems to be the only way.